# Issues with Twilio Transcription during recording within a Dial verb

Tags: twilio

I am Raj, an independent Twilio consultant for a customer.

As part of a solution implementation, we have a requirement to support the following -
"A Customer makes a call to a Twilio number which forwards the call to a business number and record the conversation".

We have configured the Twilio Number to route the request to our server and we send the following TwiML as a response :

```
<Response>
<Dial record="true">XXXXXXXXX</Dial>
</Response>
```

The above works fine for call forward and recording; but it does not seem to transcribe the recording.

If I send the following as a TwiML response; the recording & transcription does not seem to happen either.

```
<Response>
<Dial>XXXXXXXXXX</Dial>
<Record transcribe="true"/>
</Response>
```

Is there a limitation in the Dial verb that it can only record, but cannot transcribe?

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You are correct. Record is available as a [dial verb attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#attributes) but transcribe is not.

If you want to transcribe in this scenario you could use a 3rd party transcription service like [Rev](http://www.rev.com/).

Comment: Is this still the case with the latest version of Twilio API?